# Running srb rbi hidden-definitions gives unclear error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, sorbet, ruby-2.7

### Context

- Our team recently upgrade to rails 6 (from 5.2). AFAIK, things were working pretty well up to that point.
- We have a slightly unconventional file structure so we opted to use the `:classic` rails loader instead of `:zeitwerk`

### Problem

Whenever we run `srb rbi hidden-definitions` now we get the following:

```
Got LoadError when trying to get nested name Tilt::PandocTemplate
Got LoadError when trying to get nested name Tilt::AsciidoctorTemplate
Got LoadError when trying to get nested name Tilt::CreoleTemplate
Got LoadError when trying to get nested name Tilt::LessTemplate
Got LoadError when trying to get nested name Tilt::LiquidTemplate
Got LoadError when trying to get nested name Tilt::LiveScriptTemplate
Got LoadError when trying to get nested name Tilt::MarkabyTemplate
Got LoadError when trying to get nested name Tilt::PrawnTemplate
Got LoadError when trying to get nested name Tilt::RadiusTemplate
Got LoadError when trying to get nested name Tilt::RedClothTemplate
Got LoadError when trying to get nested name Tilt::RstPandocTemplate
Got LoadError when trying to get nested name Tilt::TypeScriptTemplate
Got LoadError when trying to get nested name Tilt::WikiClothTemplate
Got LoadError when trying to get nested name Tilt::YajlTemplate
Naming WebConsoleGot NameError when trying to get nested name WebConsole::SourceLocation_
Generating /var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.rbi with 20603 modules and 305 aliases
Printing your code's symbol table into /var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/from-source.json
Printing /var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.rbi's symbol table into /var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.5891/bin/srb-rbi:237:in `<main>'
        4: from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.5891/bin/srb-rbi:224:in `main'
        3: from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.5891/bin/srb-rbi:232:in `block in make_step'
        2: from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.5891/lib/hidden-definition-finder.rb:38:in `main'
        1: from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.5891/lib/hidden-definition-finder.rb:47:in `main'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.5891/lib/hidden-definition-finder.rb:151:in `write_constants': /var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.rbi had unexpected errors. Check this file for a clue: /var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.json.err (RuntimeError)
```

reflection.json.err (which the error points is to) is littered with countless errors that all look something like this:

```
/var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.rbi:707623: dynamic constant assignment https://srb.help/2001
      707623 |  REFERENCE = ::T.let(nil, ::T.untyped)
                ^^^^^^^^^

/var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.rbi:707624: dynamic constant assignment https://srb.help/2001
      707624 |  SETUTITSBUS = ::T.let(nil, ::T.untyped)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^

/var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.rbi:707625: dynamic constant assignment https://srb.help/2001
      707625 |  SLAICEPS = ::T.let(nil, ::T.untyped)
                ^^^^^^^^

/var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.rbi:707626: dynamic constant assignment https://srb.help/2001
      707626 |  SPECIALS = ::T.let(nil, ::T.untyped)
                ^^^^^^^^

/var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.rbi:707627: dynamic constant assignment https://srb.help/2001
      707627 |  SUBSTITUTES = ::T.let(nil, ::T.untyped)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^

/var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.rbi:707628: dynamic constant assignment https://srb.help/2001
      707628 |  VALID_CHAR = ::T.let(nil, ::T.untyped)
                ^^^^^^^^^^

/var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.rbi:707629: dynamic constant assignment https://srb.help/2001
      707629 |  VALID_XML_CHARS = ::T.let(nil, ::T.untyped)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.rbi:707618: class definition in method body https://srb.help/2001
      707618 |class REXML::Text < REXML::Child
              ^^^^^

/var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.rbi:707801: class definition in method body https://srb.help/2001
      707801 |class REXML::UndefinedNamespaceException < REXML::ParseException
              ^^^^^

/var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.rbi:707813: module definition in method body https://srb.help/2001
      707813 |module REXML::Validation
              ^^^^^^

/var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.rbi:707817: class definition in method body https://srb.help/2001
      707817 |class REXML::Validation::ValidationException < RuntimeError
              ^^^^^

/var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.rbi:707829: dynamic constant assignment https://srb.help/2001
      707829 |  DEFAULT_ENCODING = ::T.let(nil, ::T.untyped)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.rbi:707830: dynamic constant assignment https://srb.help/2001
      707830 |  DEFAULT_STANDALONE = ::T.let(nil, ::T.untyped)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/var/folders/w4/01z4c79j22l59fhcgyl43f8w0000gn/T/d20200911-19233-vy4tg3/reflection.rbi:707831: dynamic constant assignment https://srb.help/2001
      707831 |  DEFAULT_VERSION = ::T.let(nil, ::T.untyped)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

### Question

Any suggestions on how to move forward? One hunch is that we need to migrate to `:zeitwerk` to resolve this, but that's a pretty large refactor for us so I'm hesitant to explore that without confirming that that is a potential source for this failure.

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective. Also, please make sure to post everything relevant to answering your question *in your question*, not on some third-party site somewhere else. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: As it wasn't the type of thing people would need to copy/paste I figured it would be easier to digest as an image. I fixed it though

Comment: @JörgWMittag The question was updated to include text instead of images, and it has already been satisfactorily answered based on the details in the question, so I think this can be reopened now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: A variant of this patch has [now been upstreamed into Sorbet](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/pull/3422) and will be available in versions >= 0.5.5911. For anyone using those versions, this answer is no longer relevant.

---

I doubt that the error you are seeing is caused by any Rails configuration. The lines that you have posted from `reflection.json.err` do not show any real errors, either.

It looks like you are on Ruby 2.7, so I suspect that the error you are seeing is because of how the argument forwarding is done in 2.7 via `def foo(...)` method definitions. At runtime these turn into `def foo(**, &&)` in Ruby, and when Sorbet tries to generate the argument names, it fails, since `*` and `&` are not valid argument names.

You can try to patch the relevant method in `sorbet` gem using the diff I include below:

```
diff --git a/lib/serialize.rb b/lib/serialize.rb
index aec19ccb2..301793856 100644
--- a/lib/serialize.rb
+++ b/lib/serialize.rb
@@ -337,6 +337,14 @@ class Sorbet::Private::Serialize
           uniq += 1
         end
       end
+
+      # Sanitize parameter names that are not valid
+      name = name.to_s.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/) do
+        result = '_' + (uniq == 0 ? '' : uniq.to_s)
+        uniq += 1
+        result
+      end
+
       [kind, name]
     end
   end
```

You can use `bundle open sorbet` to open the `sorbet` gem installed as part of your `Gemfile` in your editor, apply the diff above and re-run the hidden definitions generator. If that solves your problem, I'd be happy to PR it upstream to get it in the next sorbet release.

Comment: minor update, i think you meant the `sorbet` gem, not the runtime gem. regardless, thanks again!

Comment: @ChristopherChangchien thanks for the correction. I edited the answer to correct that. I was waiting for someone to verify that that change fixes the problem for them to send the patch upstream. I'll do that today; thanks for verifying.